# C++ imitating properties from C#

Tags: c++, properties, macros

I really miss get/set in C++, so I'm trying to do something similar. This is what I have now:

```
#pragma once
#define Property(T) class : public property<T>
#define Get(T) T* get() override
#define Set(T) T* set(T* _value) override
#define MutableProperty(T) using property<T>::operator=
#include <ostream>


template<typename T>
class property
{
protected:
    T* value;
    virtual T* get() = 0;
    virtual T* set(T* _value) = 0;
public:
    property()
    {
        value = NULL;
    }
    ~property()
    {
        delete value;
    }
    T* operator=(T* _value)
    {
        return set(_value);
    }
    T* operator=(T _value)
    {
        return set(new T(_value));
    }
    operator T*()
    {
        return get();
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, property& prop)
    {
        return out << *prop.get();
    }
};
```

and this works like this:

```
#include "Property.h"
Property(string)
{
    Get(string)
    {
        return value;
    }
    Set(string)
    {
        return value = _value;
    }
public:

    MutableProperty(string);
} strprop;

int main()
{
    strprop = "teststring";
    cout << strprop;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

which I already like how it looks, but is there any trick of getting rid of those Get(type) Set(type)?
Also, is this actually good approach or this is poor code?

Comment: Related: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c131-avoid-trivial-getters-and-setters

Comment: No those getters and setters are just to show how it works, the question is about another thing @Passerby

Comment: It seems a bad idea, you're shoehorning a feature from another language using macros which are better avoided. What you have is a wrapper around a type which doesn't add anything imho. In your example you could have used `std::string` to achieve the exact same behavior. Also you're leaking memory all over as you're using `new` in set, but `operator =` doesn't call `delete`.

Comment: @al3c a good point on delete in operator=. But about no functionality - this is just example of what I have now, obviously I would use just public std::string to reproduce this example. But instead I wanna achieve a get/set for some complex getters/setters, where in get{} I will do some work before returning a getter value and so on.